# php and nested json: how can i access this element?

Tags: php, json

Here's the json text:

```
{
"data": {
    "current_condition": [{
        "cloudcover": "75",
        "humidity": "63",
        "observation_time": "03:41 PM",
        "precipMM": "0.0",
        "pressure": "1020",
        "temp_C": "15",
        "temp_F": "59",
        "visibility": "16",
        "weatherCode": "116",
        "weatherDesc": [{
            "value": "Partly Cloudy"
        }],
        "weatherIconUrl": [{
            "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png"
        }],
        "winddir16Point": "SSE",
        "winddirDegree": "160",
        "windspeedKmph": "7",
        "windspeedMiles": "4"
    }],
    "request": [{
        "query": "Northville, United States Of America",
        "type": "City"
    }],
    "weather": [{
        "date": "2013-09-24",
        "precipMM": "0.0",
        "tempMaxC": "20",
        "tempMaxF": "67",
        "tempMinC": "8",
        "tempMinF": "47",
        "weatherCode": "113",
        "weatherDesc": [{
            "value": "Sunny"
        }],
        "weatherIconUrl": [{
            "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
        }],
        "winddir16Point": "ESE",
        "winddirDegree": "111",
        "winddirection": "ESE",
        "windspeedKmph": "10",
        "windspeedMiles": "6"
    }]
}
```

}

I'm trying to echo 'temp_F' and it is not working. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I get this far:

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://blahblahblahblah");
$arr = json_decode($url,true);
```

And that's where it all fails. I've done var_dump's so I know the data is there. But every 'echo' attempt I've tried only results in 'Array' being displayed to the screen. I've tried many variations of the following:

```
echo $arr->{'data'}->{'current_condition[0]'}->{'temp_F'};
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You should actually see `Trying to get property of non-object ...` if your error reporting is activated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) with `TRUE` as second parameter gives you an associative array. But you're currently trying to access it as an object.

Try the following:

```
echo $arr['data']['current_condition'][0]['temp_F'];
```

Answer (score 1):

That´s not how you access arrays in PHP

```
$array['index']="value";

echo $array['index1']['index2']
```

For your example:

```
echo $arr['data']['current_condition'][0]['temp_F']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json to retrieve json result to a variable and then use variable information to display in js.

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'GET',
    'url': 'abc.com,
    'dataType': 'json',
    success: function (data) {

    var response = data;
    // alert(response.data.current_condition)  //something like that
    // for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) { }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach loop condition like below:

```
$url = file_get_contents("http://blahblahblahblah");
$arr = json_decode($url,true);
foreach($arr as $data)  {
   echo $data['current_condition'][0]['temp_F'];
   echo $data['request'][0]['query'];
   echo $data['weather'][0]['date'];
}
```