# Json PHP Output Numbers(Integer)

Tags: php, json

I hope I'm right here.

I am making a search engine and take my Data from a json-file(url) 
I can read out the text with my code (php)

```html
<?php 

foreach ($obj['Products'] as $key => $value) {
echo '<p>Artikel: '.$value['ProductName']. '</p> <br/>';
echo '<p> Produktbeschreibung: '.$value['Description'].'</p> <br/><br/>'; 

echo '<a href="' .$value['Deeplink1'].'" target="_blank"> zum Shop </a><br/><br/>';

}


$service = "http://dateck-media.de/sf/ddd.php ;This is the JSON // Put together request $request = $service . "?" . http_build_query($params); Get response $response = file_get_contents($request,TRUE); $obj = json_decode($response,true);
```

but now i want to show the results of my search. in my json file it looks like

```
Array ( 
    [ProductsSummary] => Array ( 
        [Records] => 20 
        [TotalRecords] => 41 
        [TotalPages] => 3 
        [CurrentPage] => 1 
    ) 
    [Products]
```

I don't know how to get the `[Totalrecords]` in my code to ECHO `"You have [TotalRecords] for your search"`

Please help me.

Comment: Number of Search Results , i mean ! I need the TotalRecords =>41 in my html file with <php echo...>

Comment: If your JSON file looks like that, it is not JSON. Also, the code you provide seems unrelated to your question. Is there any problem with that code? Can you provide the exact content of your JSON file, and how you convert it?

Comment: $service = "https://product-api.affili.net/V3/productservice.svc/JSON/SearchProducts";  This is the JSON  // Put together request
    $request = $service . "?" . http_build_query($params); Get response
    $response = file_get_contents($request,TRUE); $obj = json_decode($response,true);

Comment: This answer should help you figure the correct syntax out.
[php and nested json: how can i access this element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986602/php-and-nested-json-how-can-i-access-this-element)

Comment: i have to put a query word to get the json result... and than it looks Array ( [ProductsSummary] => Array ( [Records] => 20 [TotalRecords] => 41 [TotalPages] => 3 [CurrentPage] => 1 ) [Products] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [LastShopUpdate] => /Date(1481728714810+0100)/ [LastProductChange] => /Date(1481282050000+0100)/ [Score] => 2.846435 [ProductId] => 187755748 [ArticleNumber] => 4434361 [ShopId] => 181 [ShopTitle] => myToys.de - Einfach alles für Ihr Kind [ProductName] => Masha Köchin [Description] => Das Essen ist fertig! Mhh… das durftet aber wunderbar, denn die kleine Mascha....

Comment: Please put the information in your question, not in the comments. BTW, the link does not work.

Comment: the link only works with the data in it ! http://dateck-media.de/sf/searchform.php test that a search for a babyproduct and look ! At the top i want to shop how many products it find. this information is in the TotalRecords Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the total as follows (outside of the loop you have):

```
echo "You have {$obj['ProductsSummary']['TotalRecords']} results for your search";
```

Comment: oh thx trincot !!! thats it ! i see ... i forget the { by {$obj['ProductsSummary'].... thank youuuu

Answer (score 0):

Thx to all and sorry for my English... now i will try to put the Total- and CurrentPages at the End of the search, to go forward to the next site! But first i try alone :-)