# many layer nest in php

Tags: php, arrays, nested

```
{
    "errorMessage": null,
    "hotels": [{
        "hotelId": 1177,
        "hotelName": "Marriott",
        "hotelFilters": [{
            "filterName": "pool",
            "message": "yes"
        }]
    }, {
        "hotelId": 1542,
        "hotelName": "Hilton",
        "hotelFilters": [{
            "filterName": "pool",
            "message": "no"
        }, {
            "filterName": "spa",
            "message": "yes"
        }]
    }
```

How do I traverse the array to get a table with hotelID, hotel Name and message?  I'm lost in the levels of the array.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What about starting with "json_decode"?

Comment: Yes - so I have $data = json_decode($jsondata,true);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
{
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n"; but I'm not sure how to drop into the hotel part of the array.

Comment: In that case you get an array in PHP and the "hotels" is an array, too. So you could do `foreach($data['hotels'] as $hotel) { echo "{$hotel['hotelId']}: {$hotel['hotelName']}\n" };`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php and nested json: how can i access this element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986602/php-and-nested-json-how-can-i-access-this-element)

Answer (score 1):

Take this as a first approach ;)

```
 /**                                    
 * Transforms JSON Hotel data to PHP array
 * 
 * @param $data The data as JSON String
 * @return array|bool
 */
public function transformHotelDataFromJson($data)
{
    $_data = json_decode($data);
    if (array_key_exists('hotels', $_data) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $myData = [];
    foreach ($_data['hotels'] as $hotel) {
        $myData[] = [
            'id' => $hotel['hotelId'],
            'name' => $hotel['hotelName'],
            'message' => $hotel['hotelFilters']['message'],
        ];
    }
    return $myData;
}
```