# what's the best way of extracting a json value from a nested string?

Tags: php, json

in the code below, i would like to get the id and result code

```
{
      "data": {
      "transaction": {
                "id": "K3446tdgt08pe5QRgQ879",
                "status": "Success."
            }
        },
        "status": {
            "message": "Success.",
            "code": "200",
            "resultcode": "ESB000010",
            "success": true
        }
    }
```

Comment: So first step is json_decode()..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php and nested json: how can i access this element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986602/php-and-nested-json-how-can-i-access-this-element)

Comment: what about ```$arr = json_decode($str, true); echo $arr["data"]["transaction"]["id"]; echo $arr["status"]["resultcode"]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am expecting **$json_string** include the JSON result.

```
<?php
$array = json_decode($json_string, true);
echo $array ["data"]["transaction"]["id"];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The format you've is `JSON`, to get desired data *(the id and result code)*. You need to decode it back to an object using `json_decode` and access your desired data by `->` operator.

```php
$data = '{
      "data": {
      "transaction": {
                "id": "K3446tdgt08pe5QRgQ879",
                "status": "Success."
            }
        },
        "status": {
            "message": "Success.",
            "code": "200",
            "resultcode": "ESB000010",
            "success": true
        }
    }
';
$obj = json_decode($data);
echo $obj->data->transaction->id; // K3446tdgt08pe5QRgQ879
echo $obj->status->resultcode; // ESB000010
```